# auto (usb) tethering when phone is connected?

Tags: cyanogenmod, tethering, automation, usb-tethering

Can I somehow **auto** turn on

- usb tethering when I connect my
- HTC Desire with Cyanogenmod 7.0.3 to my
- Windows 7 computer?

NOTE Not when I connect it to anyother computer though.

Comment: Your phone is managed by the computer when connected, so you'd need to set something up computer-side.  Perhaps some sort of script to get `adb` to run a tethering app on your phone, I don't know.  Even if the phone started the tethering itself it would require something PC side to tell it that it's connected to the right computer.

Comment: So phone cannot 'know' what computer it is connected to?

Comment: Right. You could think about it this way, perhaps it's more intuitive: When you connect your phone to a PC for the first time, the PC installs the driver for your phone after getting determining what device it is.  But you phone does not install a driver for your PC, since it does not determine what PC it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [EasyTether](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mstream.easytether_beta&feature=search_result), you can always have it enabled on your device and simply right click the icon in the tray (Windows) or enable it via terminal (Linux) and be on your way. Not quite 'default' but one click is pretty good. And EasyTether uses nothing when you're not attached to a computer, so no wasted battery or processing. It does display a notification icon to be persistent (not be killed), but you might be able to turn it off.

As far as it knowing, you have to have the client installed, so any computer you hook it to that didn't both have the client and have you enable it computer-side would do nothing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sounds good. The thing is that I connect my phone the the computer and then I have to turn on tethering. It takes some time for computer to pick up the connection but sometimes tethering won't start. Not sure why. An icon in Windows sounds great. Does it mean that when I connect to my office computer and do nothing, tethering won't start? It starts only when I click the icon in Windows?

Comment: `THE LITE VERSION BLOCKS HTTPS, INSTANT MESSENGERS AND GAME CONSOLE TETHERING.` does that mean the the application filters the connection???

Comment: the lite version blocks certain protocols and https:// connections i believe. the full version (while pricey) is unrestricted and has raving reviews. And as far as the turning on, that's the beauty of it, is after running it once, you can always have it activated on the phone, making it a one step process on the computer. And yes, you're still required to right click the icon and say `Connect` in Windows, otherwise nothing will happen. You might be able to write a script to enable it and attach it to the "Always do (...) when this device is connected" in Windows...